# Powershell - Can't unlock BitLocker as 256 characters long password contains special characters with single double quotes

Tags: windows, powershell, special-characters, securestring, bitlocker

Here's the background and I have no clue beyond this so tell me how to move ahead from this!

```
PS C:\> $SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "fjuksAS1337" -AsPlainText -Force

PS C:\> Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint "E:" -Password $SecureString
```

My password here is:

```
cF;TA" X%jl"\G{d}rcVzNI=Inps#|P,o{~"k<+@?bm)PjQf^\c8EB! (cL.ZyA.v/yYQ#,!#gN'%"VwlNFs)(h\1Uf@cFdr7BU%zDA;&2R_3w3C3td-Nm,^VFE$cF>N{ol0Y~qR2i`Vm%Q@ckh0]#ZE!ijnirg5k?bj\L;88wBhg8QqO^/T64D@O6Q'H"")/I5(d4v7RC`jH=JH+,Zy*TY4MEf~.b7?;';zLEmB>F^S7aBrUfnN&(Vuhjw}Z3w5
```

As you see it has multiple single and double quotes which breaks the SecureString command output getting nowhere.

I need to use this password in order to unlock BitLocker drive as the UI throws wrong password error and recovery password of 48 digits is unfortunately lost!

Please help as I am having no idea here at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single-quoted here-string.
Anything you put in there won't be escaped in any way.

**Example**

```
$PlainTextPassword = @'
cF;TA" X%jl"\G{d}rcVzNI=Inps#|P,o{~"k<+@?bm)PjQf^\c8EB! (cL.ZyA.v/yYQ#,!#gN'%"VwlNFs)(h\1Uf@cFdr7BU%zDA;&2R_3w3C3td-Nm,^VFE$cF>N{ol0Y~qR2i`Vm%Q@ckh0]#ZE!ijnirg5k?bj\L;88wBhg8QqO^/T64D@O6Q'H"")/I5(d4v7RC`jH=JH+,Zy*TY4MEf~.b7?;';zLEmB>F^S7aBrUfnN&(Vuhjw}Z3w5
'@

$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $PlainTextPassword -AsPlainText -Force
```

For a quick reference:

```
# verbatim string. Nothing get processed. Single-quotes within the string need to 
# be doubled down.
$sq = 'Hello '' world.'

# Expandable string. Stuff that can be expanded will be.
# Double-quotes within the string need to be doubled down or preceded by a backtick `
$dq = "Hello `" "" world"

# verbatim here string. single-quotes within the string do not need to be escaped
# This is the way to go for multiline strings
$sqh = @'
Hello ' World
'@

# Expandable here string. Double quotes within the string do not need to be escaped.
# This is the way to go for multiline strings
$dqh = @"
Hello " World
"@
```

**Reference**

[About_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: This really helped and I don't have words to thank you enough and just let me tell you that this let me breath normally again!